# Sencha ExtJS 4 Linked Combobox Issue

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, extjs, frameworks

I'm experimenting what seems to be a bug in ExtJS 4 Combobox AJAX Store.

I have a grid with articles, each **article** has a **supplier** and a **category**, each **supplier** offer articles that belong to a certain **category**. In order to filtre the grid i've put 2 Combos(Select Lists). One for **supplier** and one for **category**. These combos get their values by AJAX from a php script.

Everything went good till i tried to link the combos like this:

When the user selects a **category** from the combobox, the **supplier** Store refreshes with suppliers that offer that category (works fine!).

The the user selects a **supplier** from the combobox, and the **category** Store refreshes(refresh is good, as seen with firebug).

Here is my issue now, if the user selects the **category** combobox again it, the loading mask doesn't go away so it can't change the value of the combo.

I've tested and the AJAX is working fine, it's just a EXTJS 4 issue with the Loading Mask.

The issue is happening both ways:

**A)**

**1.** User selects a category

**2.** User selects a supplier

**3.** User CAN'T select a category(loading mask doesn't go away)

**AND**

**B)**

**1.** User selects a supplier

**2.** User selects a category

**3.** User CAN'T select a supplier(loading mask doesn't go away)

**EDIT:**

The problem seems to also occur on these situation(and vice-versa: supplier->category)

**1.** User selects a category

**2.** User changes the category

**3.** User CAN'T select a supplier(loading mask doesn't go away)

Here are my models:

```
    Ext.define('Category', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'name'},
            { name: 'id'}
        ]
    });

    Ext.define('Supplier', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'name'},
            { name: 'id'}
        ]
    });
```

Here are my stores:

```
    var categoryStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Category',
        autoLoad: true,
        remoteSort: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'GetCategorysForSupplier',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
            },
            extraParams: {
                supplier: 0
            }
        }
    });

    var supplierStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Supplier',
        autoLoad: true,
        remoteSort: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'getSuppliersForCategory.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
            },
            extraParams: {
                category: 0
            }
        }
    });
```

And here are my combos:

```
    var categoryFilterCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        xtype: 'combo',
        store: categoryStore,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'id',
        fieldLabel: 'Category Filter',
        listeners: {
            change: function(field,newVal) {
                if (Ext.isNumeric(newVal)) {
                    supplierStore.proxy.extraParams.category = newVal;
                    articleStore.proxy.extraParams.category = newVal;
                    supplierStore.load();
                    articleStore.load();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var supplierFilterCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        store: supplierStore,
        displayField: 'name',
        queryMode: 'local',
        valueField: 'id',
        fieldLabel: 'Supplier Filter',
        listeners: {
            change: function(field,newVal) {
                if (Ext.isNumeric(newVal)) {
                    categoryStore.proxy.extraParams.supplier = newVal;
                    articleStore.proxy.extraParams.supplier = newVal;
                    categoryStore.load();
                    articleStore.load();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Kind Regards,

Dan Cearnau

Answer (score 1):

Look here for the answer: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?152324-4.0.7-ComboBox-bug-with-load-mask

There ldonofrio says:
This is a 4.0.7 bug, seems to be solved in 4.1pr

My override 
PHP Code:

```
Ext.override(Ext.LoadMask, {
      onHide: function() { this.callParent(); }
});
```